# Bash Functions Order and Timing

Tags: bash, function, variables, process

This should be easy to answer, but I couldn't find exactly what I was asking on google/stackoverflow.

I have a bash script with 18 functions (785 lines)- ridiculous, I know I need to learn another language for the lengthy stuff. I have to run these functions in a particular order because the functions later in the sequence use info from the database and/or text files that were modified by the functions preceding. I am pretty much done with the core functionality of all the functions individually and I would like a function to run them all (One ring to rule them all!).

So my questions are, if I have a function like so:

```
function precious()
{
rings_of   #Functions in Sequence
elves      #This function Modifies DB
men        #This function uses DB to modify text
dwarves    #This function uses that modified text
}
```

Would variables be carried from one function to the next if declared like so? (inside of a function):

```
function men()
{
...
frodo_sw_name=`some DB query returning the name of Frodo's sword`
...
}
```

Also, if the functions are called in a specific order, as seen above, will Bash wait for one function to finish before starting the next? - I am pretty sure the answer is yes, but I have a lot of typing to do either way, and since I couldn't find this answer quickly on the internet, I figured it might benefit others to have this answer posted as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables persist unless you run the function in a subshell. This would happen if you run it as part of a pipeline, or group it with `(...)` (you should use `{ ... }` instead for grouping if you don't want to create a subshell.

The exception is if you explicitly declare the variables in the function with `declare`, `typeset`, or `local`, which makes them local to that function rather than global to the script. But you can also use the `-g` option to `declare` and `typeset` to declare global variables (this would obviously be inappropriate for the `local` declaration).

See this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-variables/) on variable scope in `bash`.

Commands are all run sequentially, unless you deliberately background them with `&` at the end. There's no difference between functions and other commands in this regard.

Comment: Maybe advice against using global variables, though.  The OP's description sounds like there's horrible spaghetti code between the lines, as it were.

Comment: I probably do have horrible habits. Don't really know. I just find what works, but I have only been using Bash off and on for about 3 years. As my script is pretty long, I can see how global variables could be a bad thing. I wish I knew some best practices on coding. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @tripleee Well, I don't generally associate shell scripting with structured coding, but that's probably because I rarely consider shell appropriate for scripts longer than a few dozen lines.